# Is it possible to check that class exists while editing Spring XML files?

Tags: java, xml, spring

I use Spring with long xml files for beans.
Is it possible at edit time to check if the names of the classes are correct and all references exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, this is the responsibility of an IDE before application runtime, or a simpler class that attempts to load the configuration if spinning up the app is cost-prohibitive.

The major IDEs (Elipse, NetBeans, and Intellij) all have strong Spring support. This includes class completion, jumping between config file usage(s) and definition, gutter marks to indicate a class is a Spring bean, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [STS](http://www.springsource.com/downloads/sts), customized eclipse IDE with plugins, from Springsource. It have even auto-completion, error-checking features for writing  spring's configuration(bean.xml) files.

**UPDATE**
For further details & features: [Features of STS](http://download.springsource.com/release/STS/doc/STS-new_and_noteworthy.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Many Spring supported IDEs make suggestion of what the class name should be during editing. For example, Netbeans suggests this while you are typing the class names or other known attributes. However, it cannot be forced to check whether the class names you use really exist.

Answer (score -1):

Without additional coding effort (for example writing your own xml editor), I do not think so. That's why annotations have been invented. You can move your configuration from xml files to annotated Java classes and methods. Then your compiler will do the work automatically.